# If statements on Squib DataFrame

Tags: ruby, squib

Using [Squib](https://squib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.15.0/) to generate cards.

My csv layout is pretty simple. One of the fields could be empty - "", and depending on that field I have to do call various functions. How do I properly achieve that?

Been trying options like `data['empty_field'].empty?` and that would give me something weird - that would always think it's not empty. I assume that way I get array of 'empty_field' objects and that, of course, isn't empty. But how do I get object that Squib is currently iterating on?

Comment: "give me something weird" is a neat story, but for a technical answer please include the *exact* error text you get.

Comment: It doesn't produce any error, what's weird - I've put that in the question right after what you quote. What's placed in that 'if' never happens

Comment: Can you give us some code to reproduce this problem? Like what does `data` look like? What does `data['empty_field']` contain? `inspect` can usually tell you. If it has spaces in it, it may not be considered "empty", just blank. Within Rails you have `.present?` and `.blank?` but otherwise you might want to do `data['empty_field']&.match(/\S/)` to find at least one non-space character.

Comment: `title,description,picture,faction,power,type1,type2,type3,bottom
"Вернон Роше","Патриот, хоть и хер моржовый.",data/textures/nor_vernon.png,data/ui/ribbon/nor_tape.png,10,data/ui/type1/melee.png,data/ui/type2/type_hero.png,,data/ui/bottom/bottom_hero.png`
That is typical sample from csv file that gets loaded to DataFrame variable `data`. The `'empty_field'` is type3 in the header, and in included sample it's empty

Comment: So it should be an empty string, but can you confirm that? Sneaky things like zero-width spaces and other Excel turds can screw things up. You can dump a string with `str.bytes` to find out what it actually contains.

Comment: As a tip, it's often easier to express this like `match data['empty_field']` and then `case /\S/` for "stuff" and `else` for "no stuff". I'd double-check that `data` contains the keys you think it does, like `p data`.

Comment: Csv is generated via C# tool and I can confirm that's empty. Unless Ruby thinks otherwise on load

Comment: That's why I'm asking, repeatedly, if you can show us what `data` contains when parsed.

Comment: I've checked content of each `type3` field by dumping it to a file and console - it's empty strings, as it doesn't produce anything else
Also, as I've found it the correct way to get the field is `dataNor['type3'].map do |a| `

I'm doing this
`pr = dataNor['type3'].map do |a| 
    a == '' ? true : false
  end

  if pr == true
    text str: dataNor['power'], x: '5.5mm', y: '6.5mm', font_size: 25, color: :white, align: :center, valign: :middle, width: '10mm', height: '10mm', font: 'Warnock Pro SmBd Caption'
  else
    png file: dataNor['type3']
  end`

Comment: And I only get else called on the fields that do have type3 not empty, but the if statement is never called for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I've achieve what I wanted. But I consider it being dirty hack, rather than solution.
I had to edit my C# tool to emit empty string of `power` field where `type3` field would be empty. This way I get rid of if/else in Ruby code and it works as intended.

However issue still remains, can't wrap my head around Ruby

Attaching here my latest attempt

```
  pr = dataNor['type3'].map do |a| 
    a == 'data/ui/type3/placeholder.png' ? true : false
  end

  if pr == true
    text str: dataNor['power'], x: '5.5mm', y: '6.5mm', font_size: 25, color: :white, align: :center, valign: :middle, width: '10mm', height: '10mm', font: 'Warnock Pro SmBd Caption'
  else
    png file: dataNor['type3']    
  end
```

By printing `pr` I know that check is working, resulting in false only where `type3` is defined, however `if/else` would never call if body, and only calls else body where it should

**Update:**

The issue seems to have been fixed by this construction:

```
dataNor['type3'].map do |a| 
    if a == 'data/ui/type3/placeholder.png' 
      text str: dataNor['power'], x: '5.5mm', y: '6.5mm', font_size: 25, color: clr, align: :center, valign: :middle, width: '10mm', height: '10mm', font: 'Warnock Pro SmBd Caption'
    else
      png file: dataNor['type3']
    end
  end
```

Comment: You don't need to cast a boolean as a boolean with a ternary, the `==` comparison is fine. Likewise `if pr` is sufficient.

Comment: I've edited that as you suggested and now `if` body is being called when it should, but `else` body isn't. I'm probably missing something about Ruby, first time using it

Comment: Remember `map` will *always* return an array, so if you want to see if there's no matches, `.any?` or `.empty?`. I think what you want here is not a series of `true` or `false` entires, which is what `map` does, but `dataNor['type3'].any? { |a| a == '...' }`

Comment: As far as I understood what `#any` does - no. `dataNor['type3'].map do |a|` does what it seems to do. It gives me field from currently iterated csv line. I'm switching colors of the text using the same construction and it works just fine. However here it just doesn't

Comment: That `map` will return an array like `[ true, false, true, ... ]` which will never `== true`, so that `if` won't work as expected. You need `any?`

Comment: This would be a *lot* easier to answer if you showed a complete example including a full (Ruby) definition of `dataNor`. I don't know what you're trying to match.

Comment: As i've stated in the question title its Squib's DataFrame class

Comment: You need to give an example we can work from, like a self-contained version, as this should be a simple problem to reproduce, not one that requires digging into that library.